# `gcloud app logs read --version=[myversion]` hanging when called, never executes

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

As said in the title, `gcloud app logs read --version=[myversion]` hangs and I never see any logs. `gcloud app logs read` (without the --version) works fine. I know the version I'm using is the correct version. I did `gcloud app versions list` to make sure. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also tested the command and it seems that there is an issue with the  --version flag. I recommend you to raise a [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing this behavior.

On the other hand, as a possible workaround, you could run the command [`gcloud logging read`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/read) which doesn't have this issue.  With this command you will have to specify a [log filter](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries) and freshness, for example:

`gcloud logging read "resource.type=gae_app AND resource.labels.version_id=[VERSION_NAME]" --limit=10`

Comment: I created this [Public Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/170311834) mentioning this issue. I suggest to do a comment and start the issue so you can get notifications about this request.